# How to create new layer from text boundaries on a different layer?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, gimp

I'm starting with GIMP (trying to replace PhotoShop).

In PS I often did the following:

- Ctrl-Click on a type layer (in layer palette - to select text boundaries
- Keeping the selection, select another layer and press CTRL-J - new layer is created from the previous (type) selection - on a selected layer (from intersection of type and another layer).

How can I do this in GIMP, please ?

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your definition of text boundaries, I see 2 options :

If you want to select the actual text bounding box, you can use the *Auto-Shrink* feature of the *Rectangle selection* tool, it will fit the tool to the **content** of the layer.

If you want to select the **boundaries of the** text **layer** however, I couldn't find such a feature in vanilla gimp, but it exists in gimp's plugin registry : [Layer to Selection](http://registry.gimp.org/node/27002)

Drop the script in your script folder (*Edit > Preferences > Folders > Script*), update the scripts (*Filters > Script-fu > Refresh scripts*) or restart gimp and find the new *Layer to Selection* option in the Select menu.

Hope that helps :)